# In RxJava2, what is the meaning/significance of Observable being "non-backpressured"?

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I'm fairly new to RxJava - started learning by reading https://github.com/Froussios/Intro-To-RxJava and then continued reading at
 [What's different in 2.0](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0) to understand how RxJava2 differs.

I then tried the first example mentioned in [Backpressure (2.0)](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Backpressure-(2.0)) section and got a `MissingBackpressureException` exception as expected. However I then tried the same example again but with an `Observable` (Kotlin code) -

```
val valueProducer = PublishProcessor.create<Int>() // an  ObservableSource

valueProducer
    .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
    .map { Thread.sleep(500); it }       // slow computation
    .forEach(::println)

(0..10_000_000).forEach(valueProducer::onNext) // push 10M values
println("10M values pushed!")   // this succeeds

Thread.sleep(1_000_000)    // just hang around & notice values being printed every second
```

My question is, when the notes at [Observable and Flowable](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0#observable-and-flowable)
 mention that `io.reactivex.Observable` is "non-backpressured", what exactly does that mean? Where are the 10M values being held in the code above?

Comment: In an unbounded queue inside the `observeOn`. You risk an `OutOfMemoryError` in general.

Answer (score 0):

Backpressure means that a publisher and subscriber talk each other to let the subscriber know to the publisher that he can continue processing items in the pipeline.

If you don't have those backpressure operators.

https://github.com/politrons/reactive/blob/master/src/test/java/rx/observables/transforming/ObservableBuffer.java

Then it could happen that your subscriber start accumulating more and more item without enough time to process and you end up having an Out of memory in your system.

I recommend you to read a little bit about backpressure.

https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Backpressure

Answer (score -1):

`io.reactivex.Observable` is "non-backpressured" mean that if your data source will emitting items too often, and your subscriber will not have time for process it -> some part of data will be skipped. `io.reactivex.Flowable` are supporting backpressure, that's mean that it has method for notifying data source "Ok, i'm done with this part of data, give me another one" and data will not be lost.

Comment: By default, no data is skipped and the `Observable` dutifully tries to deliver data without losing it. There are operators to thin out the data but that's an user choice, not RxJava's.